# Is it possible to execute python scripts in EC2 instance using Amazon managed airflow dag?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, airflow

We had a EC2 instance where the python scripts located and in the same instance we have installed Airflow as well. We were able to execute those python scripts using Airflow DAGS by giving the path of the python scripts.

Now, my current requirement is to execute these python scripts using Amazon managed Airflow. Did anyone do a such implementation?

Comment: I haven't done this exactly, but I suppose you could just set up that scripts directory to be synced to an S3 bucket that you've provided to AWAA. That would give you more or less the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to add those scripts to `scripts` subdirectory in you DAG folder. The DAG folder have to be present on every worker so you can be sure that your scripts will be there too.

You can also easily get path to those files if neccessary:

```py
import os
from airflow import settings

SCRIPTS_PATH = os.path.join(settings.DAGS_FOLDER, 'scripts')
```

In that case it would be worth considering to use `.airflowignore` so the scheduler skips parsing those scripts.